# Which JavaScript lib has feature similar to Haskell's do-notation or Scala's for-comprehension?

Tags: ramda.js, for-comprehension, do-notation, sanctuary

I am exploring a few JavaScript libraries for functional programming such as Ramda, Sanctuary, etc.,. I've also checked their pipe and compose functions for chaining and composition. But they can't do something like below which use both x and y to produce the final value.

```
for {
    x <- xs
    y <- ys
} yield Point(x, y)
```

Sanctuary and similar libraries have implementations for monadic data types already. I am wondering if they also support something like do-notation or for-comprehension. May be they already have and I just couldn't find the right name of the feature. Or those libraries have their own way of solving similar problems.

Basically, I would like to be able to use do/for like construct to remove nested flatMap calls at the end of this:

```
const S = require('sanctuary')

class Book {
    constructor(title, authors) {
        this.title = title
        this.authors = authors
    }
}

class Movie {
    constructor(title) {
        this.title = title
    }
}

const books = [new Book("FP in Scala", ["Chiusano", "Bjarnason"])
    , new Book("The Hobbit", ["Tolkien"])
    , new Book("Modern Java in Action", ["Urma", "Fusco", "Mycroft"])]

console.log(books)

console.log(books.map(b => b.title))

console.log(
    books.map(b => b.title)
        .filter(t => t.includes('Scala'))
        .length
)

function bookAdaptations(author) {
    if (author === "Tolkien") {
        return [new Movie("An Unexpected Journey")
            , new Movie("The Desolation of Smaug")]
    } else {
        return []
    }
}

console.log(bookAdaptations("Tolkien"))

console.log(
    books.flatMap(b => b.authors)
        .flatMap(a => bookAdaptations(a))
)


console.log(
    books.flatMap(book => (
        book.authors.flatMap(author => (
            bookAdaptations(author).map(movie =>
                `You may like ${movie.title}, `
                + `because you liked ${author}'s ${book.title}`
            )
        )
        )
    ))
)
```

Comment: I found below library which support 'do-notation' for FantasyLand compatible monadic data types: https://github.com/FbN/yado-js/tree/main

Comment: Another option would be to use fp-ts, hoping that I can use its data types and constructs from JavaScript code. If I don't need type safety provided by TypeScript, I hope it will be fine.